# There is an invisible and unselectable image in one of my Google docs that only shows up when published. How do I remove it?

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google doc which contains an invisible and unselectable image.  I did not realize it was there until publishing the document, at which point it becomes displayed.

The best I have found is to copy everything from the document then paste it elsewhere, creating a new one.

What's extremely unfortunate is that this ghost image was actually hidden in our most foundational document template, the parent of hundreds of other documents.  Recreating them all to delete a single image is a disproportionate amount of effort and will break every link we have to the originals.

**How can I delete this ghost image?**

Comment: It isn't clear what you are dealing with. Could you [edit] the question to include a link to a document that exhibits the problem. You first can remove sensitive info.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Docs, as some other word processors, the basic structural element is a paragraph. Briefly, this means that the image might have a parent paragraph.

Using the published version as a reference, identify which might be the image's parent, then go to the source document move around other content that might be included in the same paragraph being careful of not creating a copy of the paragraph, then delete the paragraph and publish or update the published version to confirm that the image was gone.

If the above fails, it might be helpful to use "advanced" methods and tools, like using Google Apps Script or exporting the document to another format so it can be opened in an another app.

One option is to export the document as DOCX (Microsoft Word). If you don't have an installable application that can open this format without converting to another format, change the file extension from DOCX to ZIP, then uncompress the file. Once the file is uncompressed, analyze the HTML, XML, and other files created by the uncompressing process.

Comment: If you find the above too convoluted to be done by yourself, and if you are considering hiring someone, hire me! :D. I can be hired on codementor.io or directly. The links are shown in user card when hover the image.